# Silverlight callback fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, callback

Since I was to use a new method for 'getcustomers' the app doesn't work. It does get the user logged in but that is all.
What does this message tell me I must do?

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
>   was unhandled by user code
>   Message=An error occurred while trying
>   to make a request to URI
>   'https://myserver/Services/Authentication.svc'.
>   This could be due to attempting to
>   access a service in a cross-domain way
>   without a proper cross-domain policy
>   in place, or a policy that is
>   unsuitable for SOAP services. You may
>   need to contact the owner of the
>   service to publish a cross-domain
>   policy file and to ensure it allows
>   SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent.
>   This error may also be caused by using
>   internal types in the web service
>   proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute.
>   Please see the inner exception for
>   more details.   StackTrace:
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Remoting.RealProxy.Invoke(Object[]
>   args)
>          at proxy_2.EndGetLoggedInUser(IAsyncResult
>   )
>          at Caretech.Services.AuthenticationClient.GetLoggedInUserCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>          at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean
>   completedSynchronously)
>   InnerException:
>   System.Security.SecurityException
>          Message=""
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state)
>               at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>               at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>          InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
>               Message=Security error.
>               StackTrace:
>                    at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>                    at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4(Object
>   sendState)
>                    at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_1(Object sendState)
>               InnerException:  An error occurred while trying to make a
>   request to URI
>   'https://myserver/Services/Authentication.svc'.
>   This could be due to attempting to
>   access a service in a cross-domain way
>   without a proper cross-domain policy
>   in place, or a policy that is
>   unsuitable for SOAP services. You may
>   need to contact the owner of the
>   service to publish a cross-domain
>   policy file and to ensure it allows
>   SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent.
>   This error may also be caused by using
>   internal types in the web service
>   proxy without using the
>   InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute.
>   Please see the inner exception for
>   more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your silverlight app hosted on a website on a server and the webservice you are calling on another server? This is not allowed for security reasons. Either get them both on the same server or look into setting up cross-domain policy file( see [this post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx) ).

Comment: no all are on the same server. I have added the cross domain policy on the server.